# Import contacts with group

Tags: contacts, import, contact-groups, vcard

I'd like to import around 1000 contacts within a group into an android phone (OS 7.0). I have the vCard only. Is it somehow possible?

Hope this is the right place for that, thanks in advice.

Comment: Android can import vcards natively, what have you tried?

Comment: I had the same problem when importing contacts via vCard. I use "local" contacts (without google account).